# Why Share-it is not connecting to other phones not having mobile data enabled in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-730

I have trouble connecting share-it with other windows/android phones which don't have mobile data connection enabled.
When other device turned on their mobile-data , share-it connects them without trouble. Meanwhile, when other device mobile-data connection lost during file transfer, it stops sharing files and mark that file as incomplete.
Is there solution for share-it or it's due to windows 10 upgrade?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Windows 10 is problematic, so I sold phone :D

Answer (score 1):

Using Share.it between two windows phones is hell. 
As for using between a windows phone and android, even before opeening shareit, switch on the mobile hotspot on android and wifi on windows phone and connect with it. It doesnt matter if you're sending or receiving, you should only switch on wifi and android devices, their hotspots.
Use feem between two windows phones.

Store link - https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/feem-lite-wifi-file-transfer/9wzdncrcs08r
You can use it with android too but the spped is not as fast as shareit, its slightly less.
and lastly, make sure your shareit is upto date.

Answer (score 1):

**When connecting your windows mobile with an Android device**

Shareit on android device can create a hotspot without a mobile data connection on Android. Follow these steps:

1. Open Shareit on Android.
2. Click on Send
3. Select files to share.
4. Click Next. Now a hotspot will be created on Android.
5. Open Wi-Fi settings in Windows mobile.
6. Connect to the Shareit hotspot. It will be a name with random alphabets.
7. Now open Shareit and click receive.

---

**When connecting to an another Windows device**

Both the devices should be connected to the same Wi-Fi network. If you don't have a home/public Wi-Fi then using a hotspot created by your mobile data is the only option.

Comment: @Sachin My answer applies for Windows mobile. The steps vary depending on the device you want to connect your windows mobile.